# Argument of type '(prev: Phone[]) => Phone[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Phone[]'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-state

So I' m using useState with callback as an argument: `setLikedGadgets((prev: Phone[]) => [...prev, info]);`

but I recieve errors:

`Argument of type '(prev: Phone[]) => Phone[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Phone[]'. Type '(prev: Phone[]) => Phone[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Phone[]': pop, push, concat, join, and 28 more.`

on the other hand , if I use instead of `prev` code:  `setLikedGadgets([...likedGadgets, info]);`
it all works.
But how to make it work in typescript in normal way?

```js
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { likedContext } from '../context/LikedContext';
import { Phone } from '../types/Phone';

export const useLikes = () => {
  const {
    likedGadgets
    arrayOfLiked,
    setLikedGadgets,
    setArrayOfLiked,
  }
    = useContext(likedContext);

  const addToLiked = (info: Phone) => {
    if (arrayOfLiked.includes(info.id)) {
      return;
    }

    if (arrayOfLiked.length === 0) {
      setLikedGadgets([info]);
      setArrayOfLiked([info.id]);
    } else {
      setLikedGadgets((prev: Phone[]) => [...prev, info]);
    }
  };

  return { addToLiked };
};
```

by the way , type of `setLikedGadgets` is `(value: Phone[]) => void`

which I cannot change , because, thats how I defined it during createContext() initialization.

```
type LikedContextInterface = {
  likedGadgets: Phone[];
  setLikedGadgets: (value: Phone[]) => void;
  arrayOfLiked: string[];
  setArrayOfLiked: (value: string[]) => void;
};
```

Comment: Where the code says `setLikedGadgets((prev: Phone[]) => [...prev, info])`, what do you think `(prev: Phone[]) => [...prev, info]` means? What type do you expect it to have? The error message tells you that the type is `(prev: Phone[]) => Phone[]`, and that the type should be `Phone[]` instead. What exactly is your understanding of this?

Comment: Hi, so basicly thats a callback , where prev is previous value of LikedGadgets state ,
and after assignment operator I return nev value to setState hook which will be array including previous values and new one. type of info in `Phone`, type of prev is `Phone[]`

Comment: Okay, so. The error message is clear: the function expects you to give it *an array of Phones, and not* a callback that will create an array of Phones from an input array of Phones. If you want to give it a callback, then it has to be set up in the interface to accept a callback. Where is the `prev` information supposed to come from? What part of the code is intended to call the callback, and how? Please think carefully about *how you intend for the overall system to work*. Write everything out in full sentences first.

Comment: Great. Then question is: how to give `setLikedGadgets `  an array of phones and not a callback that will give me an array of phones. I discribed you the way how setState works in React js , but errors appear because of typescript. Prev is an argument that callback function recieves automaticly.

Comment: "Prev is an argument that callback function recieves automaticly." **When**? **From where?** "how to give setLikedGadgets an array of phones" Well, clearly you know how to write code that describes an array of Phones. What happens if you try writing `setLikedGadgets(`, and then an array of Phones, and then `)`? **Why do you want** to use the callback? What *practical problem do you hope it will solve*?

Comment: Hint: I see something in your interface called `likedGadgets`, which is an array of Phones. Can you think of a way to use this information, in combination with `info`, in order to figure out what array of Phones should be used for the `setLikedGadgets` call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
type LikedContextInterface = {
  likedGadgets: Phone[];
  setLikedGadgets: (value: Phone[]) => void;
  arrayOfLiked: string[];
  setArrayOfLiked: (value: string[]) => void;
};
```

In this definition, `setLikedGadgets` is a function that takes in an array of phones.  Passing a function to `setLikedGadgets` violates the type, so typescript shows you an error.

Based on the way you're using it, it appears that `setLikedGadgets` is a react state-setter function. That would mean it can either take the new value, or it can take a function which computes the new state from the old state. If you want to preserve that behavior, then that information will need to be included in the type.

If you want to import the types from react, they are:

```
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react';

type LikedContextInterface = {
  likedGadgets: Phone[];
  setLikedGadgets: Dispatch<SetStateAction<Phone[]>>;
  arrayOfLiked: string[];
  setArrayOfLiked: (value: string[]) => void; // <--- this may want similar treatment
};
```

Or if you want to write it yourself, you could do:

```
setLikedGadgets: (value: Phone[] | ((prev: Phone[]) => Phone[])) => void;
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Nicholas Tower, here is solution to the problem, summed up.

So, bug was in createContext initialization, more specificly type defentition of initial values. Here is already FIXED code.

```
import { createContext, useState } from 'react';
import { Phone } from '../types/Phone';

type LikedContextInterface = {
  likedGadgets: Phone[];
  setLikedGadgets: (value: Phone[] | ((prev: Phone[]) => Phone[])) => void;
  likedGadgetsID: string[];
  setLikedGadgetsID: (value: string[] | ((prev: string[]) => string[])) => void;
};

export const likedContext = createContext<LikedContextInterface>({
  likedGadgets: [],
  setLikedGadgets: () => {},
  likedGadgetsID: [],
  setLikedGadgetsID: () => {},
});

type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

export const LikedContextProvider: React.FC<Props> = ({ children }) => {
  const [likedGadgets, setLikedGadgets] = useState<Phone[]>([]);
  const [likedGadgetsID, setLikedGadgetsID] = useState<string[]>([]);

  return (
    <likedContext.Provider value={
      {
        likedGadgets, setLikedGadgets, likedGadgetsID, setLikedGadgetsID,
      }
    }
    >
      { children }
    </likedContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

in type of `LikedContextInterface` I wrongly set type of state-setter functions `setLikedGadgets` and  `setArrayOfLiked`:

before

```
setLikedGadgets: (value: Phone[]) => void;
```

which meant that it was allowed only to recieve argument of type Phone[]

after

```
setLikedGadgets: (value: Phone[] | ((prev: Phone[]) => Phone[])) => void;
```

now it can recieve either `value: Phone[]`  , or `((prev: Phone[]) => Phone[]))` - callback , that with argument of type Phone[], and return Phone[].

also `Dispatch<SetStateAction<Phone[]>>` wasn't working for me , since type defenition was outside function component.